# VS2005 Database Project ignoring target database name on deploy

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, deployment, visual-studio-2005, database-project

I'm working on an ancient project made in VS2005 that deploys a database project to SQL Server 2005.

The project has a database name configured in the `Target Database` field in the `Build` tab of the project properties. Testing the connection confirms that the settings are correct.

I usually overwrite this database using `SSMS` with backups downloaded from different production servers, then rebuild the database project to generate an SQL script with the statements required to apply recent schema changes to the production DB.

I'm not sure what might have changed, but recently it started to generate a different DB named like this: `ProjectName_DB_GUID`, interfering with the creation of the diff script.

It also deleted many rows in some tables, even though `Block Incremental Deployment if data loss might occur` was checked.

This apparently happens only with some of the downloaded databases, but so far I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause.

What might I be missing here? What can I try to diagnose the problem and restore the original behavior?

Comment: Are you using VSDBCMD to push the changes around? Assuming you can reproduce, can you generate a script instead of pushing the changes directly?  Can you look into upgrading this project to SSDT or even a newer version of VS?

Comment: Sadly, upgrading is not an option as my job is to just keep the app alive while migration to a newer solution takes place. I don't use VSDBCMD, I just rebuild the database project as described and then run the generated diff script on the target server. I have to do this manually because the servers are on a Citrix VPN.

Comment: You may want to check out the vsdbcmd functionality (may need VS2008/10). When I had to use DB Projects, that was the best way to deploy/generate the script. You can override whatever options are being passed using a command line.  Also, if your migration will take longer than a couple of months, you may still benefit from using SSDT - it's a little more robust in quite a few ways and is the currently supported version. (It's also free if you use an "express" VS edition for the IDE.)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like VSDBCMD is only available on 2008/10 as you suspected, and for reasons that go way beyond the scope of the question, upgrading from VS2005 is not really an option. However, it suddenly started working again. Looks like a VS bug to me so far, but thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Glad that it started working. Shame that you can't upgrade from VS2005. MS made a lot of leaps between that and 2010 and with SSDT being free to use, it's much better on the whole than VSTSDB. I understand that your hands are tied, but if you have any leeway to test it out, you might appreciate the improvements. Even just having a command line like in VS2008+ is an improvement. :)